# Error of int cannot be dereferenced?

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error with this constructor, and i have no idea how to fix? I am a beginner at java. This is from an example exercise that i was trying to learn:

```
/** 
 * Create an array of size n and store a copy of the contents of the
 * input argument
 * @param intArray array of elements to copy 
*/
public IntArray11(int[] intArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    String [] Array = new String[intArray.length];
    for(i=0; i<intArray.length; ++i)
    {
    Array[i] = intArray[i].toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please use proper conventions: method names and variable names should start with a lowercase letter

Answer (score 24):

`int` is not an object in java (it's a [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)), so you cannot invoke methods on it.

One simple way to solve it is using 
[`Integer.toString(intArray[i])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int))

Answer (score 6):

I would write it more like this

```
public String[] convertToStrings(int... ints) {
    String[] ret = new String[ints.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; ++i)
        ret[i] = "" + ints[i];
    return ret;
}
```

Or in Java 8 you might write

```
public List<String> convertToStrings(int... ints) {
    return IntStream.of(ints).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(toList());
}
```

This uses;

- Java coding conventions,
- limited scope for the variable `i`,
- we do something with the `String[]`,
- give the method a meaningful name,
- try to use consist formatting.

If we were worried about efficiency it is likely we could do away with the method entirely.

`String.valueOf(int)` is not faster than `Integer.toString(int)`. From the code in `String` you can see that the String implementation just calls Integer.toString

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code int} argument.
 * <p>
 * The representation is exactly the one returned by the
 * {@code Integer.toString} method of one argument.
 *
 * @param   i   an {@code int}.
 * @return  a string representation of the {@code int} argument.
 * @see     java.lang.Integer#toString(int, int)
 */
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You code tries to call the toString() method of an `int` value. In Java, `int` is a primitive type and has no methods. Change the line:

```
Array[i] = intArray[i].toString();
```

to

```
Array[i] = String.valueOf(intArray[i]);
```

and the code should run. By the way, you should use lowerCamelCase for variables and fields.

Edit: For what it's worth, String.valueOf(int) is a bit faster than Integer.toString(int) on my system (Java 1.7).

Comment: See my answer as to why String.valueOf cannot be faster than Integer.toString ;)

Comment: Then it's probably a benchmark artefact. I knew I should have used JMH for measurement, but my mvn repository had some breakage recently.