# Int cannot be dereferenced, how would I fix it?

Tags: java

I am new to writing Java codes and this website, and I wondered why I get the error *int cannot be dereferenced*?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  a = 4;
    int b = 4;
    if(a > b){
        
        print(a.toString());  
    }else if(a < b){
        print(b.toString());
    }else if(a == b){
        print("Values are equal.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to add that "print()" is a function I added for "System.out.println".

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, so you can't dereference it with the `.` operator. You can, however, use `String.valueOf(int)`

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, you should [edit] it.

Comment: You should've got a compilation error at a.toString()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error of int cannot be dereferenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213083/error-of-int-cannot-be-dereferenced)

Comment: @DeepanshuRathi: that's exactly what they got and what the ask about.

Comment: Why `print(a.toString());` instead of `print(a);`?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your integers like `Integer a = 4` then you can use .toString() method