# How does the .decode() method work in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, decode

I need to make a calculator that can work with numbers of up to ten, both Arab and Roman numbers. I decided to use the *String* method *.compareTo()* to help my program figure out whether it's one or the other. Now, I want to convert numerical *Strings* to *Integers*. I [found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) an *int* method for decoding *Strings* to *ints*, but it doesn't appear to work: it returns an error

```
Introduction.java:52: error: int cannot be dereferenced
      firstNum = firstNum.decode(firstNumS);
                         ^
Introduction.java:90: error: int cannot be dereferenced
      secondNum = secondNum.decode(secondNumS);
```

Why is that? Here's my code (bear with me, it may be a bit clumsy)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Introduction {
  static int firstNum = 0;
  static int secondNum = 0;
  static double result;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String firstNumS = "1";
    String secondNumS = "2";
    String operationS = "+";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    firstNumS = scanner.next();
    operationS = scanner.next();
    secondNumS = scanner.next();
    if(firstNumS.compareTo(operationS) > 15){
      switch(firstNumS){
      case "I":
      firstNum = 1;
      break;
      case "II":
      firstNum = 2;
      break;
      case "III":
      firstNum = 3;
      break;
      case "IV":
      firstNum = 4;
      break;
      case "V":
      firstNum = 5;
      break;
      case "VI":
      firstNum = 6;
      break;
      case "VII":
      firstNum = 7;
      break;
      case "VIII":
      firstNum = 8;
      break;
      case "IX":
      firstNum = 9;
      break;
      case "X":
      firstNum = 10;
      break;
      default:
      System.out.println("I don't know the first number!");
    }
    } else {
      firstNum = firstNum.decode(firstNumS);
    }
    if(secondNumS.compareTo(operationS) > 15){
      switch(secondNumS){
      case "I":
      secondNum = 1;
      break;
      case "II":
      secondNum = 2;
      break;
      case "III":
      secondNum = 3;
      break;
      case "IV":
      secondNum = 4;
      break;
      case "V":
      secondNum = 5;
      break;
      case "VI":
      secondNum = 6;
      break;
      case "VII":
      secondNum = 7;
      break;
      case "VIII":
      secondNum = 8;
      break;
      case "IX":
      secondNum = 9;
      break;
      case "X":
      secondNum = 10;
      break;
      default:
      System.out.println("I don't know the second number!");
    }
    } else {
      secondNum = secondNum.decode(secondNumS);
    }
    if(operationS == "+"){
      result = firstNum + secondNum;
    } else if(operationS == "-") {
      result = firstNum - secondNum;
    } else if(operationS == "*"){
      result = firstNum * secondNum;
    } else if(operationS == "/"){
      result = firstNum / secondNum;
    } else {
      System.out.println("I don't know such an operation!");
    }

    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error of int cannot be dereferenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213083/error-of-int-cannot-be-dereferenced)

Answer (score 3):

[`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)) is a `static` method that belongs to the wrapper class `Integer`, not the primitive `int` (primitives don't have methods anyway):

```java
firstNum = Integer.decode(firstNumS);
```